# Create a loading bar

Tags: c#

I want to create a simple loading bar. So I placed two PictureBox on the form. One for cover the whole form, one for display a centered loading spin (with Image property).

I want to use this loading bar when the program is loading (and when some heavy task is running).

But the loading spin does not show while the form is loading. By the way, the whole form is empty during loading.

How can I solve it? If I can...

I have no code, but there is a sample below:

```
 private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000); //some heavy task
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Some example is welcomed.

Comment: Come on code show your self

Comment: Hint: There is a progressbar control in windows forms

Comment: @EpicKip Seems after all that that wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Putting a `Thread.Sleep` (or any long-running piece of code) in your event handler will block the UI until that event handler is done running its code.

You have to put such code in a `BackgroundWorker`, `Thread` or `Task` and run that code asynchronously. In that way, the code can run independently from the UI, which will make the UI responsive.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using async and await. This makes it possible to let another task work in the background while the ui still can be responsive.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

private async void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Start the loading animation here

    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        // Do work here!
    });

    // When the task is complete, stop the loading animation
}
```

Note that everything done in the task is done on another thread in my example, so I would really recommend you to learn about multi threading also.

Comment: `async void`. This won't work. `async void` is only meant for event handlers. What you posted as a "Load" function should be placed in the event handler instead.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, that is true. I simplified the code so that it was placed inside the event delegate where void is used as a return type. Otherwise it should of course return some type of Task.

Comment: You didn't *simplify* it. This is actually broken

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how is it broken?

Comment: [Start here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx). Are you sure, really sure, that your code can *run* after the `await`? On which thread? This event handler will exit immediatelly after the call to `Load()`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos why wouldn't the code after the await run when the task is completed? See examples from Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)